# Printing out a buffer in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to convert an input of base 10 to binary and I am trying to store it in input_buffer then print out input_buffer. When I try to its not printing anything as if it were empty for reference here's what I have:

```
.data
ask_input: .asciiz "Enter a number (0-255): "
binary: .asciiz "\nThe number in base 2 is: "
input_buffer: .space 10

.text
.globl main

main:
    # Ask for input
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, ask_input
    syscall

    # Assign input
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $s0, $v0 # Integer is stored in $s0

    # Setup
    li $t0, 2    # For dividing by 2
    li $t1, 0    # For holding binary
    li $t2, 8    # Assume 8-bit binary response

    # Initialize the input_buffer with null bytes
    li $t3, 0      # Null byte
    li $t4, 10     # Number of bytes to initialize
    la $t5, input_buffer  # Address of input_buffer

    initialize_buffer:
        sb $t3, ($t5)   # Store a null byte
        addi $t5, $t5, 1  # Move to the next byte
        addi $t4, $t4, -1  # Decrement the byte count
        bnez $t4, initialize_buffer  # Continue until all bytes are null

convert_loop:
    # Continue the loop until $s0 is not equal to 0
    bnez $s0, continue_conversion

    # If $s0 is 0, jump to printing the binary
    j print_bin

continue_conversion:
    # Use 'and' with 1 for the least significant digit
    andi $t3, $s0, 1

    # Convert the least significant digit to '0' or '1'
    addi $t3, $t3, '0'

    # Store the ASCII character in input_buffer
    sb $t3, input_buffer($t2)

    # Right shift for division by 2
    srl $s0, $s0, 1

    # Decrement the counter
    addi $t2, $t2, -1

    # Continue the loop
    j convert_loop

print_bin:
    # Print the output message
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, binary
    syscall

    # Print the binary representation stored in input_buffer
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, input_buffer
    syscall

    # Exit
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: Numbers in registers are already in binary, you can get the bits with shift and AND.  Using `div` would be much less efficient.  Apparently you already figured that out, but forgot to take out an instruction that was putting `2` in a register.  `li $t0, 2    # For dividing by 2` .  Your code doesn't use `$t0` after that, so this instruction is just clutter.

Comment: When you single-step your code in a debugger, what do you see in memory when you get to the system-call?  Is there ASCII data in a buffer that isn't getting printed, or is it all spaces or zero bytes?  An [mcve] should include debugging details.

Answer (score 1):

You're storing the digits backwards into the buffer — starting from the end of the buffer working backwards.  Your conversion loop stops when the input value becomes 0.  So, for an input value like 3, it stores '1' then '1' and then stops.  The buffer then looks like this:

```
0   0   0   0   0   0x31 0x31 0
^               ^
input_buffer    t2 (as index)
```

Then you print from the beginning of the buffer, which is null, so of course, nothing prints.  The syscall #4 for printing strings stops at the first null it sees, i.e. it prints a null-terminated string.  It would be silly for the syscall to ignore nulls until it finds proper characters to print, then honor the null ending the string, no?  The reason is that an empty string is a valid string, a string of zero length, and systems (syscalls, printf, etc..) handle that very normally.

---

To address this, you could do *one* of the following (hint one of them is easier than the others):

- initialize the buffer with spaces, 0x20, instead of nulls

  and that would print leading spaces followed by 11, or,
- print the buffer, not from the beginning, but from where the conversion loop stopped

  using `la $a0, input_buffer+1($t2)`, or,
- copy the string from where it was placed into the end of buffer to the beginning of it.

  If you do this extra copy, there's really no reason to have worked backwards in the conversion, as can do the copy backwards instead.  Probably want to use a separate 2nd buffer, but can be made to work with just one buffer, if careful about edges.  Less efficient though due to making the copy.

---

Given that you're storing into the buffer, there's really no need to initialize it with nulls.  If your algorithm uses the buffer precisely, it will overwrite any old values there, even if the program runs the user input, conversion, output in a loop.

But since it isn't running in a loop, the null initialization is already done as the program is loaded into memory, since the .space directive instructs on that.  Of course that will only be done once at the beginning of the program.  (Though as I said if you use the buffer properly, any new output would overwrite old output obviating the null byte initialization.)

---

In the following

```
addi $t5, $t5, 1  # Move to the next byte
```

this should be using `addiu` instead of `addi`, because this is pointer arithmetic, and pointer arithmetic is unsigned integer arithmetic.  Using `addi` risks signed overflow exception, which is not just irrelevant but wrong for unsigned arithmetic.  However, given the starting addresses and range you're using for data, this problem won't manifest.  If your program was using the heap, and lots of it, this logic error might show (as an unwanted exception stopping the program).

Comment: `la $a0, input_buffer+1($t2)` - usually you'd have a pointer in a register, not an index, since the OP's `sb $t3, input_buffer($t2)` can only work with the `.data` section in the low or high 32KiB of virtual address space.  (Unless `sb` gets treated as a pseudo-instruction, not restricted to a signed 16-bit displacement).  But anyway yeah, since you're already storing there, you definitely have an easy way to generate a pointer in a register to the last byte you stored.  This might not be "obvious" to think of, but seems obviously best and easy to understand, and should be the first choice.

Comment: @PeterCordes, that form allows 32-bit address + register.  It expands to 3 instructions, yuk!  I wish the assemblers didn't allow that.  Still, I decided go with the OP's style here , rather than exploring a more "proper" way to do array indexing or just use pointers since the program is doing all sequential accesses.